# How to get ckeditor to format entire text, no selection?

Tags: ckeditor

We have simple formatting requirements and want to use ckeditor to format a single line of text. I've disabled <kbd>ENTER</kbd> so only a single line can be entered. But how do I get the formatting to apply to the entire text entered and disallow the user from selecting text?